# Installed Node.js but File Cannot be Found by Command Prompt

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I installed *node.js* onto my Raspberry Pi, which is running on Raspbian Stretch.

To install, I used the command `$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`. There were no problems with installation.

When I try to test the installation by typing `$ nodejs -v` into the command prompt, it returns

```
nodejs: command not found
```

If I try to install it again, the prompt returns

```
nodejs is already the newest version (8.11.1~dfsg-2~bpo9+1)
```

Also, when I look into my `/usr/bin` folder, I see that *node.js* is there.

I've spent a while searching for what could be causing this issue to no avail. I think maybe the *node.js* file is in the wrong folder, but none of the tutorials I've read has a step where you would move the file.

Any help to get *node.js* to work would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: try `node -v` instead? `nodejs` is the apt package name, the actual executable is just `node`.

Comment: I get the same error when trying what you said.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1040 Seems like you are not alone. (Also looks like a bunch of working solutions there.)  Personally I can recommend nvm, but then again I know nothing about raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Step 1: This command updates our Debian apt package repository to include the NodeSource packages.

`$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -`

Step 2: Install NodeJS (THis will ensure you are installing latest version)

`sudo apt install -y nodejs`

Step 3: Enjoy NODEJS in RaspberryPi

```
$ node -v
v10.6.0
$ node
> 1 + 3
4
> # We can hit Ctrl-C twice to exit the REPL and get back to the bash (shell) prompt.
```

If you are having conflicts with previous NODE installations, do this to remove all existing installations:

Running `which node` will return something like `/path/bin/node`

Then run `cd /path`

Then run `rm -r bin/node bin/node-waf include/node lib/node lib/pkgconfig/nodejs.pc share/man/man1/node.1`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. It seems like I have conflicts with previous NODE installations, however when I run `which node`, it returns nothing. I also checked and there is no `/path/bin/node` folder.

Comment: I ended up just re-etching Raspbian on my micro-SD so I can start fresh. What you recommended worked, I now have NODE installed on my Pi. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Glad it helped @HilalKesim